# How to associate custom taxonomy terms with custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

how to associate custom taxonomy terms with post type insert into wp_term_relationships table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$catids = $_POST['artticle_category'];
/*
 * If the ids are coming from the database or another source, we would 
 * need to make sure these were integers or convert them to interger using intval:
 */

$catids = array_map( 'intval', $catids );
$catids = array_unique( $catids );
$taxonomy = 'articles_category';
$post_id = '1';

$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $catids , $taxonomy );
```